select que muestre seleccion segun se haga en otro select
Hola a todos espero me puedan ayudar con esto...
Tengo un select (municipio) el cual me muestra un listado de una tabla como opciones de selección: Al ser seleccionado una opción de este select me gustaria que en otro select (operar) cargue la consulta dependiendo de esa selección inicial..
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <select name="municipio" class="campos" id="municipio" required>
               <option value="">SELECCIONE:</option> 
               <option value="Todos">TODOS</option>         
                  <?php
                 $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE estado='activo' AND pqr='1' ORDER BY municipio ASC");
                  while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $qq=$valores[municipio];
                    echo '<option value="'.$valores[municipio].'">'.strtoupper($valores[municipio]).'</option>';
                     }
                    ?>
          </select>
          
          
          
          <select class="campos" name="operar" id="operar">
                 <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                 <option value="Todos" selected="selected">TODOS</option>
                    <?php
              $query2 = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM datos_archivo WHERE municipio='$qq' ORDER BY municipio ASC");
              while ($valores2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$valores2[nombre].'">'.strtoupper($valores2[nombre]).'</option>';
              }
            ?>
          </select>
    
    
    <script>
    $(function(){   
    $("#municipio").on('change', function(){// blur es es cuando dejas el foco
            dato=$(this).val();//tomamos el valor ingresado en el campo
    $.ajax({//enviamos via ajax el post hacia consulta donde enviamos como variable dato (podes porner mas separados por comas, dato:valo, nombre:valor2.....)
      type: "POST",
      url: "consultass.php",
      data: { dato: dato }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {//msg es el nombre que le dimos a lo que nos devielve ajax, que es lo que imprime el script consulta.php
      $("#operar").html(msg);
      //aca le decimos que el contenido html de el select sera el valor de msg
    
      });
            
            })  
        })
    </script>

esta es la consulta del archivo consultass.php que llama ajax
<?php 
$qq=$_POST['dato'];
          $query2 = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM datos_archivo WHERE municipio='$qq' ORDER BY municipio ASC");
          while ($valores2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
             $salida.='<option value="'.$valores2[nombre].'">'.strtoupper($valores2[nombre]).'</option>';

          }
          echo $salida;

?>


Hola. En el segundo  select tienes que quitar la consulta a la base de datos, pues es Ajax quien debe hacer esa consulta en cada cambio. Por otra parte, en el código de consultass.php debes definir $salida antes del while como una variable en blanco: $salida=""; para luego poder concatenar dentro del while. Y no te recomiendo trabajar los datos en el servidor, es mejor devolver un JSON y armar los option en el cliente usando .each(). El problema es que si hay comillas en el contenido o problemas con la codificación, te creará un HTML inválido.

Bueno ya alli viendo tutoriales y guiandome de ejemplos pude realizarlo..
La parte del Formulario con el select y un div donde se cargara el select mostrando la lista según la selección inicial..
<select name="municipio" class="campos" id="municipio" required>
                <option value="">SELECCIONE:</option>         
                <?php
 echo '<option value="Todos">TODOS</option>';
          $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE estado='activo' ORDER BY municipio ASC");
          while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$valores[municipio].'">'.strtoupper($valores[municipio]).'</option>';
 }

        ?>    
              </select>
              


                   
    
                
                
                   
                   
                  
                  
                   
                
el select inicial tiene id municipio el cual al ser cambiado "dispara" la acción del siguiente script (script que viene mas abajo de este mismo código.(obviamente mas arriba el CDN de Jquery para que todo funcione...)
<script>
    function recargarLista() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "consultass.php",
            data: { dato: $('#municipio').val() },          
            success: function(r) {
                $('#select2lista').html(r);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

al hacer el cambio en el select se activa la función que llama a un archivo php consultass.php enviándole el dato del select vía post y esto recibe luego una respuesta y muestra el resultado en el div con id #select2lista.
este es el archivo consultass.php:
<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$user = "usuario";
$password = "contrasena";
$database = "basededatos";


$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
if(!$conexion){
echo "No se realizo la conexion a la basa de datos, el error fue:".
mysqli_connect_error() ;
}

$codigo = $_POST['dato'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla2 WHERE municipio='$codigo' AND estadotrabajador='ACTIVO' ORDER BY nombre ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

// EL SELECT A MOSTRAR------------------------------------------------------
echo '<select name="operar" class="campos" id="operar">';
echo '<option value="" selected>SELECCIONE</option>';
echo '<option value="Todos">TODOS</option>';                 
while ($ver = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$ver[nombre].'">'.strtoupper($ver[nombre]).'</option>';
}
echo  '</select>';    

?>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.campos').select2();
    });
</script>

pero tengo un problema todo funciona bien, se hace la búsqueda y al momento de ir atrás no permanece el resultado del segundo select (obviamente por que es un fichero php cargado) como hago para que al darle regresar a la búsqueda permanezca en este select el listado generado, (en los otros campos incluido el select 1  si permanece todo)

Recuerda que el formato del sitio es de preguntas y respuestas. Si ya tienes respuesta completa a tu pregunta, formula otra con el nuevo problema. Si la pregunta nueva (la que está actualmente en tu respuesta) sigue estando relacionada a la actual pregunta, entonces ponla como edición a la misma.

cierto!! siempre lo olvido.. pero al editar se pierde el hilo de la consulta o como es?? pues y gracias!!!! lo puse por si alguien lo necesitaba..

Al editar tu pregunta, estás agregando más detalles acerca de la misma. Cuando estás respondiendo a tu propia pregunta, es porque se asume que ya encontraste alguna solución al problema.

por lo mismo al editar mi pregunta (el código por ejemplo.. ) no se pierde el hilo en la conversación de la pregunta?? es decir puede confundir a los que leen la pregunta pues no quedaría el código expuesto si no el código solucionado?? allí si me perdí

@Eduardo un sitio de Q&A no funciona como un Foro o como una red antisocial, aqui no se maneja el concepto de "hilos". El formato es: 1 pregunta bien definida y una o más respuestas a dicha pregunta. Si al solucionar el primer problema, encuentras otro diferente, debes formular otra pregunta.

Esta solución no es buena, por lo que te comenté en la pregunta. Si en los datos hay comillas o tienes un problema con el charset, se producirá un HTML inválido. Es mejor que devuelvas un JSON y que luego en Javascript crees el select o lo llenes, según lo que quieras hacer, que dicho sea de paso, no queda claro. Inicialmente parecía que querías llenar el select a cada cambio, ahora parece que quieres crear un select por cada cambio ¿? Esto último podría ser problemático, por ejemplo, si el usuario selecciona el mismo elemento más de una vez, ¿crearás select repetidos?
